# Populate dropdown from array on the basis of multiple dropdown values

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

Please guide me how can I make this code better.

```js
var employees_json = [
    {"id":"1","departments_id":"1","designations_id":"1","employee_types_id":"1","name":"name1"},
{"id":"2","departments_id":"2","designations_id":"2","employee_types_id":"1","name":"name2"},
    {"id":"3","departments_id":"3","designations_id":"3","employee_types_id":"2","name":"name3"},
    {"id":"4","departments_id":"4","designations_id":"4","employee_types_id":"3","name":"name4"},
    {"id":"5","departments_id":"5","designations_id":"5","employee_types_id":"3","name":"name5"}
];

$("._employee_selection").change(function() {
  update_employees();
});

function update_employees() {
  var departments_id = $('#departments_id').val();
  var designations_id = $('#designations_id').val();
  var employee_types_id = $('#employee_types_id').val();

  options = '<option value="">Select an option</option>';
  $.each(employees_json, function(index, val) {
    var selection = 0;

    if (departments_id == '' || val.departments_id == departments_id) {
      selection += 1;
    }
    if (designations_id == '' || val.designations_id == designations_id) {
      selection += 1;
    }
    if (employee_types_id == '' || val.employee_types_id == employee_types_id) {
      selection += 1;
    }

    if (selection == 3) {
      options += `<option value="${val.id}">${val.name}</option>`;
    }
  });

  $("#employees_id").html(options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="departments_id" class="_employee_selection">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select an option</option>
<option value="1">Administration</option>
<option value="2">Data Entry</option>
<option value="3">Development</option>
<option value="4">Management</option>
<option value="5">Marketing</option>
</select>

<select id="designations_id" class="_employee_selection">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select an option</option>
<option value="1">Administration</option>
<option value="2">Data Entry</option>
<option value="3">Development</option>
<option value="4">Management</option>
<option value="5">Marketing</option>
</select>

<select id="employee_types_id" class="_employee_selection">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select an option</option>
<option value="1">Permanent</option>
<option value="2">contract</option>
<option value="3">Probation</option>
</select>

<select id="employees_id">
</select>
```

What is a better way to populate a dropdown on the basis of multiple dropdown selections?

This is basically a search filter and I'm not doing an Ajax to fetch data from filtered dropdowns.

I have a json array of employees with their department, designation and type in each element of array.

From the dropdown above selected in any combination, I'm trying to populate the employee list.

The following code is working for me, But I'm hoping for an easy and better way of doing it, which I'm not sure how can be done more efficiently.

Comment: Can their be multiple of the same department and can the designation be different?

Comment: No. Everything is unique. There will be only these 3 dropdown as in jsfiddle.

Comment: So is their a need for the designation list? I'm talking about your JSON is their repeated data?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because recommendations for code improvement are more suited for CodeReview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Look at https://jsfiddle.net/kpduncan/xyu9cgzh/ (I think for the user it simpler to lock the fourth input until all three are filled).

Comment: @kodecount actually all dropdown are optional, and I only need to populate the employee dropdown on the basis of selection. an employee has department, designation and type. if user select `Administrator-Administrator-permanent` then employee named `name1` should be fetched from array and populate in dropdown. if only permanent is selected then 2 employess should be populated. etc.

Comment: Ah. That makes more sense. Still it make sense to disable it when the filters are invalid. I updated the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the help. your solution is very similar to what I already have. I was looking for something smaller. I am actually disabling the employee dropdown. just posted a lighter version of mu code. Thanks